# Flash Error message when Validation Fails while using FormResquest

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5, laravel-6

I am using FormRequest to do my validations. I am trying to set a top-level error message via Flash to show to the user that the form submission did not succeed.

Right now I have the following UserResquest

```
class UserRequest extends FormRequest {
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'first_name' => 'required|string|min:2|max:50',
            'last_name' => 'required|string|min:2|max:50',
            'date_of_birth' => 'required|date',
            'gender' => 'required|in:male,female'
        ];
    }
```

I am trying to do this in my Controller

```
$validator = $request->validated();

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            Session::flash('error', $validator->messages()->first());
            return redirect()->back()->withInput();
        }
```

But the Flash message is turning up empty. **whats the best way to set the Flash Error message when using `FormRequest`**

Am setting my Flash Message as following the View Template.

```
<div class="flash-message">
                @foreach (['danger', 'warning', 'success', 'info'] as $msg)
                    @if(Session::has('alert-' . $msg))
                        <p class="alert alert-{{ $msg }}">{{ Session::get('alert-' . $msg) }} <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a></p>
                    @endif
                @endforeach
            </div> <!-- end .flash-message -->
```

Comment: you dont need to do it in your controller. `FormRequest` does it automatic

Comment: @N69S where can I set it? or display it in the View?

Comment: Please mark your question as answered if any answer worked out for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FormRequest` does it automatically, you dont have to handle it in the controller.

it does so in

```php
protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
{
    throw (new ValidationException($validator))
                ->errorBag($this->errorBag)
                ->redirectTo($this->getRedirectUrl());
}
```

You can overload the method if you want another behavior.

To get the error messages, you need to fetch it in the error bag

```html
{{ $errors->default->first('first_name') }}
```

the error bag is named `default` by default, you can change it in your `FormRequest` extended class

**Custom messages**

To set the message per error, declare the following method in your `UserRequest` class

```php
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'first_name.required' => 'A first name is required',
        'first_name.min'  => 'The first name can\'t be a single character',
        ...
    ];
}
```

And to know if there are errors, check the variable `$errors->default` in your blade then you can show the message "The Form did not save. Check below for the error and try again"

Comment: Any way to set the message? or how can I show it in the view? any particular syntax? Success message is displaying. Only having issue with Error

Comment: Okay I think i was not clear. I am getting the field level error message. I am trying to set the Form Flash message such as.. "The Form did not save. Check below for the error and try again"

Comment: @HarshaMV added more details in the answer

Comment: I have updated my question with my view on how I am trying to display the Flash Message. I think you are trying to show the Field errors. I am trying to set the Top-level message for the Form so people know the submission was not successful.

Comment: @HarshaMV just do `@if($errors->default->any())` or just `@if($errors->any())` guess it works for all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199563/discussion-between-harsha-m-v-and-n69s).

Answer (score 3):

As N69S pointed out. We can set it under `failedValidation` as below.

```
/**
     * Handle a failed validation attempt.
     */
    protected function failedValidation(\Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator $validator)
    {
        session()->flash('alert-danger', 'There was an error, Please try again!');
        return parent::failedValidation($validator);
    }
```